# How to iterate through these arrays at the same time?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, foreach

I have multiple nested loops and some arrays that I want to iterate through at the same time.

Now, the first array contains data in somehow chaotic order:

```
ArrayOne ( 
    [1298] => Array ( 
        [manuf comment for dev 1] => Array ( 
            [comment 1 for IMEI no. 277745.5] => 1298 
        ) 
    ) 
    [1312] => Array ( 
        [0] => Array ( 
            [comment 3 for IMEI no. 570] => 1312 
        ) 
    ) 
    [1318] => Array ( 
        [0] => Array ( 
            [comment 2 for IMEI no.576] => 1318 
        ) 
    ) 
)
```

As you can see above, there are three arrays (I know they look weird but that's how they are set and I can't change them).

next array is:

```
ArrayTwo ( [0] => 1321 [1] => 1322 [2] => 1323 )
```

Important note: the length of `ArrayOne` and `ArrayTwo` will ALWAYS be the same. So if `ArrayOne` contains THREE arrays, `ArraTwo` will contain THREE values inside.

The way I am iterating now is this:

```
foreach ($ArrayOne as $devices_id => $manuf_comments) {
    foreach ($manuf_comments as $mc => $client_comments) {
        foreach ($client_comments as $cl => $ff) {
          echo "</br>MANUF COMMENTS: "; 
          print_r($mc); 
          echo "</br>DEV comments: ";
          print_r($cl);
          echo "</br>DEV id: ";
          print_r($devices_id);
          echo "</br>*";
    }
  }
}
```

The loop above prints:

```
MANUF COMMENTS: manuf comment for dev 1
DEV comments: comment 1 for IMEI no. 277745.5
DEV id: 1298
*
MANUF COMMENTS: 0
DEV comments: comment 3 for IMEI no. 570
DEV id: 1312
*
MANUF COMMENTS: 0
DEV comments: comment 2 for IMEI no.576
DEV id: 1318
*
```

As you can see using the nested foreach I am able to print properly the `ArrayOne` values ,however if I try to loop through `ArrayTwo` inside these foreach loops, it will go 3 times because there are Three arrays in `ArrayOne`. **So, the question is, how can I loop properly through `ArrayTwo` inside the existing for loops?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use another variable to hold the index into `ArrayTwo`, and just increment it in the same loop.

```
$indexTwo = 0;
foreach ($ArrayOne as $devices_id => $manuf_comments) {
    $eltTwo = $ArrayTwo[$indexTwo];
    foreach ($manuf_comments as $mc => $client_comments) {
        foreach ($client_comments as $cl => $ff) {
            echo "</br>MANUF COMMENTS: "; 
            print_r($mc); 
            echo "</br>DEV comments: ";
            print_r($cl);
            echo "</br>DEV id: ";
            print_r($devices_id);
            echo "</br>*";
        }
    }
    $indexTwo++;
}
```

Comment: thanks man, you seem like a guy who knows these things in sleep.